# Execute a oracle pl/sql query and return the result set based on the run time date value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have below data

```
empid date        amount
1     12-FEB-2017  10
1     12-FEB-2017  10
1     13-FEB-2017  10
1     14-FEB-2017  10
```

I need a query to return the total amount for a given id and date i.e, below result set

```
empid date         amount
1     12-FEB-2017  20
1     13-FEB-2017  10
1     14-FEB-2017  10
```

but the think is, from the UI i will be getting the date as input.. if they pass the date return the result for that date .. if they dont pass the date return the result for most recent date.

below is the query that I wrote .. but it is working partially..

```
SELECT sum(amount),empid,date
FROM employee emp,
  where
  ((date= :ddd) OR aum_valutn_dt = (select max(date) from emp))
  AND emp.id = '1'
group by (empid,date)
```

Please help..

Comment: Although you can do it directly, this kind of logic choices are better done at client level (application that uses the database).

Comment: Well the UI  team is different here.. we don't have the control on the UI side.. we need to do it at the db level..

Comment: You don't have access to the backend application?

Comment: What do you mean by backend application??

Comment: The application that is interfaced with the database is your backend

Comment: No I don't have access to the application.. we will write only pl/sql queries..

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "working partially".  What works, what doesn't. Give data supporting that claim and for what is not working show  actual and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this

but it is pretty bad you should try to do it some other way
it is doing extra work to get the most recent date

```
select amt, empid, date 
from 
(
   select amt, empid, date, rank() over (order by date desc) date_rank
   from
   (SELECT sum(amount) amt,empid,date
    FROM employee emp
    where emp.id = '1'
    and (date = :ddd or :ddd is null)
    group by empid, date)
)
where date = :ddd or (:ddd is null and date_rank=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option; scans TEST table twice so ... mind the performance.

```
SQL> with test (empid, datum, amount) as
  2    (select 1, date '2017-02-12', 10 from dual union all
  3     select 1, date '2017-02-12', 10 from dual union all
  4     select 1, date '2017-02-13', 10 from dual union all
  5     select 1, date '2017-02-14', 10 from dual
  6    )
  7  select t.empid, t.datum, sum(t.amount) sum_amount
  8  from test t
  9  where t.datum = (select max(t1.datum)
 10                   from test t1
 11                   where t1.empid = t.empid
 12                     and (t1.datum = to_date('&&par_datum', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
 13                          or '&&par_datum' is null)
 14                  )
 15  group by t.empid, t.datum;
Enter value for par_datum: 13.02.2017

     EMPID DATUM      SUM_AMOUNT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 13.02.2017         10

SQL> undefine par_datum
SQL> /
Enter value for par_datum:

     EMPID DATUM      SUM_AMOUNT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 14.02.2017         10

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT sum(amount),empid,date
FROM employee emp,

where date =nvl((:ddd ,(select max(date) from emp))

AND emp.id = '1'
group by (empid,date)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is following:

```
with t (empid, datum, amount) as
      (select 1, date '2017-02-12', 10 from dual union all
       select 1, date '2017-02-12', 10 from dual union all
       select 1, date '2017-02-13', 10 from dual union all
       select 1, date '2017-02-14', 10 from dual
      )
select empid, datum, s
  from (select empid, datum, sum(amount) s, max(datum) over (partition by empid) md
          from t
         group by empid, datum)
 where datum = nvl(to_date(:p, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), md);
```

Calculate maximal date in the subquery and then, in outer subquery, compare the date with `nvl(to_date(:p, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), md)`. If the paremeter is `null`, then the date field is compared with maximal date.